# Mensagem de erro Method not found: class Bean

Tags: jsf-2.2, java-bean

Essa é a mensagem de erro aprensentado;

```
mai 25, 2015 3:40:55 PM com.sun.faces.context.SessionMap put
ADVERTÊNCIA: JSF1063: AVISO! Definindo valor de atributo não serializável em HttpSession (chave: produtoMB, classe do valor: managedBean.ProdutoManagedBean).
mai 25, 2015 3:40:55 PM com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy handleRenderException
GRAVE: Error Rendering View[/index.xhtml]
javax.el.ELException: /index.xhtml: Method not found: class managedBean.ProdutoManagedBean.uploadAction()
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.AttributeInstruction.write(AttributeInstruction.java:94)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UIInstructions.encodeBegin(UIInstructions.java:82)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:302)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.renderRow(GridRenderer.java:185)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren(GridRenderer.java:129)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:889)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:889)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:456)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:133)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1086)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:659)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1558)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Esse é meu web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>

        <filter-class> org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>  
</web-app>
```

essa é minha pagina

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<h:head>
    <title>File Upload</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h1>Inserir Produto</h1>
    <h:form>
        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                Nome: <h:inputText value="#{produtoMB.produto.nome}" />
                Preço: <h:inputText value="#{produtoMB.produto.preco}" />

                Foto: <p:fileUpload id="upload" update="foto"
                fileUploadListener="#{produtoMB.uploadAction}" auto="true" />

            <h:commandButton action="#{produtoMB.salvar}" value="Salvar" />
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>

    <h2>Produtos Cadastrados</h2>
    <h:form>
        <h:dataTable var="produto" value="#{produtoMB.listarProdutos}">
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Foto</f:facet>
                <h:graphicImage value="./image/#{produto.foto}" />
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Nome</f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{produto.nome}" />
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Preço</f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{produto.preco}" />
            </h:column>

        </h:dataTable>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Porque será que está dando o erro?

Esssa é minha classe Bean.

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package managedBean;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import entidades.Produto;
import dao.ProdutoDao;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.primefaces.event.FileUploadEvent;
/**
 *
 * @author Mara
 */
@ManagedBean(name="produtoMB")
@SessionScoped
public class ProdutoManagedBean {
    private Produto produto;
    private List<Produto> listarProdutos;
    private UploadArquivo arquivo = new UploadArquivo();

    public ProdutoManagedBean() {
        this.produto = new Produto();
        this.listarProdutos = new ArrayList<Produto>();
    }

    public List<Produto> getListarProdutos() {
        return new ProdutoDao().listar();
        //return this.listarProdutos;
    }

    public void setListarProdutos(List<Produto> listarProdutos) {
        this.listarProdutos = listarProdutos;
    }

    public Produto getProduto() {
        return produto;
    }

    public void setProduto(Produto produto) {
        this.produto = produto;
    }

    public void uploadAction (FileUploadEvent event){
        this.arquivo.fileUpload(event, ".jpg", "/image/");
        this.produto.setFoto(this.arquivo.getNome());
    }

    public void salvar(){
        new ProdutoDao().salvar(produto);
        this.arquivo.gravar();

        this.produto = new Produto();
        this.arquivo = new UploadArquivo();
    }
}
```

Comment: Qual versão do PrimeFaces você está usando?

Comment: Essa é a versão PrimeFaces-5.0, mas eu acho que não deva ser por conta da versão.